# Mongodb count distinct with multiple group fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have  transaction table which is populated by holidays taken by the employees.
I would need help on following sql scenario in mongodb.

```sql
select employee,month,year,count(distinct (holiday_type) from 
transactions group by employee,month,year
```

I need to use aggregation in mongodb and was created mongo query like this and this gives me  wrong solution

```js
db.transactions.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": { 
            "Month": { "$month" : "$date" }, 
            "Year": { "$year" : "$date" },
            "employee" : "$employee",
            "holiday_type" : "$holiday_type"
        },
        "Count_of_Transactions" : { "$sum" : 1 }
     }}
 ]);
```

I am confused in using count distinct logic in mongodb. Any suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Part of the way there but you need to get the "distinct" values for "holiday_type" first, then you [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) again:

```js
db.transactions.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": { 
            "employee" : "$employee",
            "Month": { "$month" : "$date" }, 
            "Year": { "$year" : "$date" },
            "holiday_type" : "$holiday_type"
        },
     }},
     { "$group": {
         "_id": {
            "employee" : "$_id.employee",
            "Month": "$_id.Month",
            "Year": "$_id.Year"
         },
         "count": { "$sum": 1 }
     }}
 ], { "allowDiskUse": true }
 );
```

That is the general process as "distinct" in SQL is kind of a grouping operation in itself. So it is a double [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operation in order to get your correct result.

Comment: I am getting the error as follows on executing this query      assert: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allo
w external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.",
        "code" : 16945,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed

Comment: @Karthi The memory usage limit for `$group` operations was reduced in MongoDB 2.6 but you also may have a particularly large collection. You can add "allowDiskUse" to counter that in the "options" section of the method arguments as I have included in the edit. Also see the [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) command manual page

Comment: You are right. I didnt include allowDiskuse in the query. This is very much helpful.

Comment: If I want to do a sum function for example say hours, which group segment should have the sum function say (total : $sum : $hours") this needs to be group across  month,year,employee.

Comment: @Karthi That sounds like another question and is probably better expressed as a question than a short comment. Please feel free to ask it.