# Mongodb count of distinct, sum function with group by multiple columns

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have transaction table which is populated by holidays taken by the employees. I would need help on following sql scenario in mongodb.

select employee,month,year,count(distinct (holiday_type),sum(hours) from 
transactions group by employee,month,year

I have started mongodb couple of weeks back. I have got the partial answer through is stack overflow post [Mongodb count distinct with multiple group fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650136/mongodb-count-distinct-with-multiple-group-fields)  and now am looking to add sum function.

Any guidance will be really helpful, here is a sample of the data shown in table form:

```
Employee    date      holiday_type  hours
1           1/1/2014  1             8 
1           1/5/2014  2             7 
1           2/15/2014 1             8 
1           3/15/2014 3             16 
11          1/1/2014  1             8 
11          1/5/2014  1             6 
11          2/15/2014 3             8 
11          3/15/2014 3             8
```

Comment: What exactly is hours? Where does that come from? Can you perhaps show some sample data so we have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So with "hours" actually being a field (property) within your document to begin with. So from the previous answer you just abstract the double grouping as follows:

```js
db.transactions.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": { 
            "employee" : "$employee",
            "Month": { "$month" : "$date" }, 
            "Year": { "$year" : "$date" },
            "holiday_type" : "$holiday_type"
        },
        "hours": { "$sum": "$hours" }
     }},
     { "$group": {
         "_id": {
            "employee" : "$_id.employee",
            "Month": "$_id.Month",
            "Year": "$_id.Year"
         },
         "count": { "$sum": 1 },
         "hours": { "$sum": "$hours" }
     }}
 ], { "allowDiskUse": true }
 );
```

So you are simply using [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) in both stages.

Additionally, It should be worthwhile for you to take a look at the [SQL to Aggregation mapping chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) provided in the official documentation. It has many examples of common SQL operations and how to implement them in a MongoDB way.

---

From your own data, but inserted by myself in this way:

```js
db.transactions.insert([
    { "employee": 1,  "date": new Date("2014-01-01"), "holiday_type":  1, "hours": 8   },
    { "employee": 1,  "date": new Date("2014-01-05"), "holiday_type":  2, "hours": 7   },
    { "employee": 1,  "date": new Date("2014-02-15"), "holiday_type":  1, "hours": 8   },
    { "employee": 1,  "date": new Date("2014-03-15"), "holiday_type":  3, "hours": 16  },
    { "employee": 11, "date": new Date("2014-01-01"), "holiday_type":  1, "hours": 8   },
    { "employee": 11, "date": new Date("2014-01-05"), "holiday_type":  1, "hours": 6   },
    { "employee": 11, "date": new Date("2014-02-15"), "holiday_type":  1, "hours": 8   },
    { "employee": 11, "date": new Date("2014-03-15"), "holiday_type":  3, "hours": 8   }
])
```

And not the best example since all the months are actually different but this would get "distinct" values on the "holiday_type" if it needed to group that way. The result is achieved:

```js
{
    "_id" : {
            "employee" : 1,
            "Month" : 2,
            "Year" : 2014
    },
    "count" : 1,
    "hours" : 8
}
{
    "_id" : {
            "employee" : 11,
            "Month" : 2,
            "Year" : 2014
    },
    "count" : 1,
    "hours" : 8
}
{
    "_id" : {
            "employee" : 1,
            "Month" : 1,
            "Year" : 2014
    },
    "count" : 2,
    "hours" : 15
}
{
    "_id" : {
            "employee" : 11,
            "Month" : 1,
            "Year" : 2014
    },
    "count" : 1,
    "hours" : 14
}
{
    "_id" : {
            "employee" : 1,
            "Month" : 3,
            "Year" : 2014
    },
    "count" : 1,
    "hours" : 16
}
{
    "_id" : {
            "employee" : 11,
            "Month" : 3,
            "Year" : 2014
    },
    "count" : 1,
    "hours" : 8
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Neil. I tried this, I am getting zeros on the hours column. The sample data set is  "employee" : "Karthick" <br />
 "holiday_type" : 1 <br />
 "hourrs" : 8, <br />
 "date" : 2009-01-01" <br /> <br />

 "employee" : "Karthick11" <br />
 "holiday_type" : 1 <br />
 "hourrs" : 8, <br />
 "date" : 2009-01-01" <br /> <br />

 "employee" : "Karthick12" <br />
 "holiday_type" : 1 <br />
 "hourrs" : 8, <br />
 "date" : 2009-01-01" <br /> <br />

Comment: @Karthi your `hourrs` field is spelled differently ( and incorrectly ), so you cannot just "cut and paste" and instead you need to look at the differences. Also this really should have been an edit to your question as I have already done ( or attempted from your previous comments ). So please **edit** your question in the future rather than try to post additional details ( especially data ) in comments. But I do think the general question is worthwhile to demonstrate the concept, so you got an up vote for that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In my real time data it is mentioned as "hours" only. I just populated with sample data and mispelled.  What else would have gone wrong.

Comment: @Karthi you clearly are doing something wrong in your setup. See the additional information I have provided in the answer. The query as shown works as expected.

Comment: This is working. Mistakes in my query. Thanks a lot Neil. I am understanding this logic clearly now.