# Sum the different grades by date in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using the restaurants dataset from the MongoDB website.  A document has arrays like the following:

```
{
    "grades" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-06-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : "A"
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-06-05T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : "B",
            "score" : 7
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2012-04-13T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : "A"
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2011-10-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : "A"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get a list of all dates, with a count of how many of each grade there was on that day.

I've got this far:

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([{
    $unwind : {
        path: '$grades'
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: '$grades.date',
        grades: {
            $push: '$grades.grade'
        }
    }
}])
```

Which gives me each date and the grades on that date.

How do I now count the number of each unique grade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650136/mongodb-count-distinct-with-multiple-group-fields).

The solution is actually much simpler than I was thinking:

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([{
    $unwind : {
        path: '$grades'
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            date: '$grades.date',
            grade: '$grades.grade'
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}])
```

This gives a result like:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "date" : ISODate("2014-06-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "grade" : "C"
    },
    "count" : 4
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "date" : ISODate("2011-11-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "grade" : "C"
    },
    "count" : 3
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "date" : ISODate("2014-05-06T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "grade" : "A"
    },
    "count" : 121
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "date" : ISODate("2012-08-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "grade" : "C"
    },
    "count" : 5
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "date" : ISODate("2013-09-04T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "grade" : "C"
    },
    "count" : 4
}
```